# Does autovacuum to prevent wraparound on a TOAST table lock its associated user table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, autovacuum

My understanding of the difference between autovacuum versus autovacuum to prevent wraparound is that the former can be interrupted by incoming transactions, whereas the latter will temporarily block transactions on the table until the autovac completes. The latter will be triggered when the table's transaction age reaches `autovacuum_freeze_max_age`, which is by default configured to 200 million.

The question I have is let's say we have a table that stores rows with a TEXT column. Sometimes the TEXT field will contain very few characters (less than 2Kb), whereas other times the TEXT field exceeds 2Kb, which triggers insertion into the associated TOAST table in 2Kb chunks. When there are quite a few > 2Kb rows inserted, the transaction age growth on the TOAST table will outpace the transaction age growth on the associated user table.

If my understanding of all that is correct, what will happen when an autovacuum to prevent wraparound is triggered on the TOAST table?

1. Does it also block transactions on the associated user table?
2. If it does, will it only block the transactions where the row size exceeds 2Kb (or whatever size threshold triggers the write to the TOAST table)? Or does it also block transactions for rows which don't meet the threshold for writing to TOAST table?

Comment: Autovacuum doesn't block transactions in general.  It holds a lock which blocks certain other locks.  Those locks are needed for DDL, they are not needed for basic operations like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.